# Conditions widget in protege 5

Tags: ontology, protege, restrictions

everyone, I am a new user of protege. I want to define some restrictions for my Ontology but could not locate the conditions widget or an editor that can allow me to specify the existential Restrictions. Pls how do i locate the conditions widget in Protege 5? or can i get an editor that can do this?

Thanks

Comment: In the [Class description](http://protegeproject.github.io/protege/views/class-description/) view, press "EquivalentTo" (or "SubClassOf"), then proceed to the "Object restriction creator" tab.

Comment: http://wiki.opensemanticframework.org/images/3/35/Existential_restriction_object.png

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I have seen it. what about enforcing necessary and sufficient conditions?

Comment: SubClassOf is necessary condition, EquivalentTo is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: thanks alot. i really appreciate your contribution